# How to unpack .tgz file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux

What I need is to untar / unzip random file names ending with .tgz

When I use irb (interpreted ruby via command line) this command works

```
`tar xzf *.tgz`
```

as long as I am in the appropriate directory

However, this doesn't work inside the ruby script.  I change directory by using

```
puts Dir.pwd
Dir.chdir("unprocessed/") do
   puts Dir.pwd
end
`tar xzf *.tgz`
```

This puts me in the subdirectory unprocessed, and then I try to run the tar command above.
It however gives me this error, but the same exact thing works in irb.

```
tar (child): *.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What I need is to untar / unzip random file names ending with .tgz
Then I'm going to read what is inside of those.

EDIT ----
With the help of the accepted answer, I ended up using

```
Dir.chdir("unprocessed/") do
    puts Dir.pwd
    `tar xzf #{Dir.pwd}/*.tgz`
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backticks evokes a new shell that knows nothing about `Dir.pwd` so what you want is something like this:

```
Dir.chdir("unprocessed/") do
   `tar xzf #{Dir.pwd}*.tgz`
end
```

#### or

```
Dir.chdir("unprocessed/")
`tar xzf #{Dir.pwd}*.tgz`
```

Comment: I didn't realize it did this.  Thanks!